# Ratio of two infinite cardinal numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cardinals, infinite-groups

Suppose $G$ is the group of all functions between $[0,1]\to\mathbb{Z}$. Let $H$ be the subgroup defined as $H=\{f\in G: f(0)=0\}$. Then, what can be said about the cardinality of $H$ and its index in $G$?

I think the cardinality of $H=G=2^{c^2}$, where $c$ is the cardinality of the natural numbers. Hence, I think the index is countable. Am I right? Any hints ? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: $c$ is the cardinality of the natural numbers? Do you really mean that?

Comment: How can you compose two functions $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb Z$ and $g : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb Z$ ? Your group doesn't seem well defined

Comment: @TonyK why, you mean it is wrong?

Comment: @DodoDuQuercy  This is a question I saw in an exam. The question said the group of all maps and did not mention the group operation. What could be the group operation?

Comment: I guess the group operation that would make the most sense is addition, do you agree?

Comment: The group operation is likely $fg(x):=f(x)+g(x)$, or similar, as in a group ring.

Comment: @vidyarthi, $\mathfrak c$ is universally recognised as denoting [the cardinality of the _real_ numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_(set_theory)).

Comment: @TonyK but I wrote $c$ not  $\mathfrak{c}$!

Comment: The standard symbol for the cardinality of the natural numbers is $\aleph_0$ (`\aleph_0`). But whatever you call it, squaring it leaves it unchanged. So $2^{\aleph_0^2}=2^{\aleph_0}$ (which equals $\mathfrak c$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Prove that $G/H\simeq\mathbb{Z}$ by exhibiting a **surjective** group morphism $G\to \mathbb{Z}$ with kernel $H$ (there is an obvious one).

Then deduce that $G/H$ has cardinality $\aleph_0$ ($c$, with your weird notation).

Comment: does this proof work:: we take cosets of $H $ in $G$. Now the cosets are exactly equal to $\mathbb{Z}$ depending on the value of $f(0)$. Hence the index is countable

Comment: I think a required morphism is $F(f)=f(0)$, right?

Comment: You are right :-)